# Address smart group based on mailbox? Or Tags?

Tags: mail.app, contacts, mail-rules

I have manually created mailboxes in Mail and would like to create a rule that moves all future email from those senders who currently exist in one of those mailboxes to be sent to the same mailbox. That is: Any incoming mail from a sender who already has a message from that sender in ManualMailbox_A should be *moved* into ManualMailbox_A.

Is there a way to define a smart contacts group to do this so that the Mail rule can use "Sender is member of Group"? Some other way?

I am trying to avoid having to manually fiddle with putting senders into contacts and groups, and would like to just drag message into mailbox and have all future mail from that sender redirected to same mailbox — and of course have multiple senders put into single mailboxes.

Comment: Hey, how about being able to simply "tag" messages and have rules be able to filter on tags? Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Go to **Mail** > Preferences > Rules > Add Rule.

[image]

Make sure you have created before: a target mailbox in **Mail**, and a matching address group in **Contacts** (a.k.a. Address Book). Hope this works!

Comment: My main goal was to avoid manual setup in advance of groups.  The goal is to implement a solution that allows simple dragging of mail messsages into mail folders such that in future those same senders will get auto-moved to the same folder. Your suggestion seems to still require me to manually put the sender's email address into a group in advance.

Comment: That is correct. Let me think about something else that comes closer to what you need...

Comment: It sounds like you'd need some kind of watcher script, so that when a new message is added to your key mailbox, the address book checks to see if the sender of that message is already a member of your key group, and if not, adds him. Don't ask me how to code that up, but it would work. A sideways approach to this would be to trigger a script manually on the current message to add the sender to the group (rather than dragging to a mailbox), and then filter the message.